# Can the supreme court decision to abolish affirmative action be reversed at any time?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, education, affirmative-action

https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/22pdf/20-1199_hgdj.pdf

> The Court has come to rest on the bottom-line conclusion that racial
> diversity in higher education is only worth po- tentially preserving
> insofar as it might be needed to prepare Black Americans and other
> underrepresented minorities for success in the bunker, not the
> boardroom (a particularly awkward place to land, in light of the
> history the majority opts to ignore).106 It would be deeply
> unfortunate if the Equal Protection Clause actually demanded this
> perverse, ahistorical, and counterproductive outcome. To impose this
> result in that Clause’s name when it requires no such thing, and to
> thereby obstruct our collective progress toward the full realization
> of the Clause’s promise, is truly a tragedy for us all.

Can the supreme court decision to abolish affirmative action be reversed at any time?

The Supreme Court has decided to abolish the affirmative action policy that benefited Black Americans. I am wondering if that decision can be reversed at any time and how easily it could be reversed were the government or Supreme Court decide to do so, and is there a historical precedent that shows this being done?

Comment: "What the court giveth the court taketh away."  Roe v. Wade

Comment: There are a number of well known SCOTUS reversals: Dobbs reversed Roe, Brown v Board reversed Plessy v Ferguson.

Comment: This strikes me more as a law question than a political one, but that could just be my opinion.

Comment: Regarding **"_the affirmative action policy that benefited Black Americans_**":  Was that the case?  I mean, less than half of black college students finished their degrees ([~46%% in 2021](https://research.com/universities-colleges/college-dropout-rates)), while they carried the largest student-loan burden ([~44,880 USD in 2019](https://www.investopedia.com/student-loan-debt-by-race-5193137)), while presumably competing with peers who had to meet higher benchmarks to enter classes that tend to grade them on the same scale.  Was that beneficial?

Comment: I mean, it seems like an interesting topic.  But for an assertion in a question-statement, it seems off-topic.

Comment: @Nat "benefitted" is a pretty flexible word and life is complex. Just for example, benefits can include the people you meet and contacts you make, potential letters of recommendations from professors you engage with, and... wait for it... the things you learn in class! Remember, this is *education* as well as diploma-seeking. There's nothing to say that we can not also benefit from things that have an undesired outcome. So I think that the OP's sentence is perfectly fine considering the broad range of definitions of the word "benefit". No need to read it the particular way you've singled out.

Comment: @uhoh:  I suspect that the word "_benefited_" would tend to mislead a reader interpreting it in a typical sense.  I mean, it's an "_interesting topic_" because it does involve a lot beyond what can be easily conveyed in these short comments, especially within the scope of what the comments are supposed to be for, just, because any potential benefit for students who'd be admitted only-iff affirmative-action seems, at best, speculative, the off-topic assertion that affirmative-action was beneficial would seem non-constructive.

Comment: @Nat this is an *interesting* thing that -- you are right -- we can't really explore in comments; proximally vs globally benefitting from something. But if you want something like getting into a particular school, and it seems that a program has made your wish come true, you have certainly benefitted from that program in a proximal sense (and one can argue your fellow students benefit as well (e.g. some diversity arguments also used for bussing between school districts)) and proximal benefits for individuals can't be measured with aggregated statistics. Hmm...

Comment: @uhoh: College has costs -- like debts, lost wages, and delayed career-advancement -- that, on the whole, can still be helpful.  The analysis of costs-vs.-benefits can be especially rosy for stronger, better-prepared students.  But for students who're statistically likely to drop-out with debt that they'll barely even dent after 20-years while not enjoying any resume-builders nor having acquired meaningful skills or contacts.. I dunno.  I mean, if you're aware of it being a good deal for such students, I'd be interested.

Comment: @Nat look at the term you've used: "analysis of costs-vs.-**benefits**" The way that the OP used "benefited" in the question is fine. You can receive some benefits from something without it being a good deal.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Supreme Court is reactive, not pro-active. It can only make law on an issue related to one of its previous precedents, when someone brings a lawsuit that presents an issue related to a previous precedent. And, the incentive to bring a lawsuit testing a well-established recent precedent of the U.S. Supreme Court is low.

With regard to affirmative action, to do it in one case, a college or university would have to deliberately defy the recent SCOTUS ruling on point, lose in all of the lower courts, get SCOTUS to grant certiorari to consider its twice rejected claim, and then get at least five members of the Court to rule in their favor. If the institution lost, it would be exposed to damages and attorney fees in a discrimination lawsuit for doing so.

But, when the U.S. Supreme Court has an appropriate case before it, it can overrule its past precedents at any time.

More realistically, litigants would bring multiple cases chipping away at the edges of the current precedent where it was ill-defined and try to make small gains there, until victory in an outright effort to overturn the old precedent was almost certain, before engaging in the defiant test case behavior necessary to overturn a precedent in a single ruling.

Comment: "the incentive to bring a lawsuit testing a well-established recent precedent of the U.S. Supreme Court" seems to be high if your long-term effort of filling the court with judges willing to throw out precedent has reached its goal.

Comment: Probably worth a Stare Decisis blurb, but great answer

Comment: "to do it in one case, a college or university would have to deliberately defy the recent SCOTUS ruling on point" Alternatively, a body representing African-American applicants could try to argue that race neutral admissions programs are discriminatory against them, and have standing to sue universities and work up to the Supreme Court that way.

Comment: You say that, but this court took a case this session relating to an activity the plaintiff was just *thinking* about doing, and whether said plaintiff in that theoretical event, if some other theoretical event happened, would have to provide said service they don't currently provide to anyone. So no, SCOTUS doesn't really need a real existing issue to make a ruling, it seems.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica or just for activist agitation purposes.

Comment: You could also overturn the 14th amendment via the usual amendment process, such that equal protection was no longer a constitutionally-protected right. There might be a few side effects, but affirmative action would be legally fine if racial discrimination were legally protected.